# how to Write a new calculator to accept a variable number of arguments

Tags: c#, .net, calculator

Write a new calculator to accept a variable number of arguments. 
The calculator would be launched as follows:

```
C:\>calc.exe + 2 3 6 12
```

Comment: Awesome homework, now you need to look into `params` command line arguments, `arrays` and how to use *LINQ* `Skip` and  `Sum` and most likely a `switch` statement

Comment: Did you write the calculator code? What problem you are facing int that?

Comment: Is it a full calculator that accepts polish notation? Is it just an operator then a sequence of numbers? What code have you got so far?

Comment: i just write the code to get the input from two numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int [] Number = new int[args.Length -1];

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length - 1; i++) {
            int num;
            int.TryParse(args[i + 1], out num);
            Number[i] = num;
        }

        int result;

        int.TryParse(args[1], out result);

            switch (args[0])
            {
                case "+":

                    for (int i = 1; i < Number.Length; i++)
                    {
                       result = result - Number[i];
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    break;
                case "-":

                    for (int i = 1; i < Number.Length; i++)
                    {
                       result = result - Number[i];
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    break;
                case "*":

                    for (int i = 1; i < Number.Length; i++)
                    {
                       result = result * Number[i];
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    break;


                case "/":

                    for (int i = 1; i < Number.Length; i++)
                    {
                       result = result - Number[i];
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid code");
                    break;

            }

            Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave *fault tolerance* and everything else up to you

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  switch (args[0])
  {
      case "+":
         Console.WriteLine(args.Skip(1)
                               .Select(int.Parse)
                               .Sum());
         break;
  ...
```

Comment: @Senthuja i was afraid of this. it takes some command line arguments, test if the first is `+` then uses Linq to iterate over the rest (skipping the first one), converting them all to `int` and summing them all

Comment: yah sure. thank you